# Using moment with Typescript 1.8 and ES6

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I installed the moment definition files through typings:

`typings install moment --save`

So far so good but when I import the definitions in the following way:

`import * as moment from 'moment';`

All compiles fine but when I run my application I receive a runtime error:

`Uncaught TypeError: moment is not a function`

How exactly does should the moment library be imported?

if I instead use:

`const moment = require('moment');`

Everything works, but I lose all the type safety.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "ES6",
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noLib": false,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "meteor_core",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you reference / import your definition files (typings folder)?

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: The referencing is done by the typings module, it creates two main definition files: broswer.d.ts and main.d.ts. For all other npm packages with provided typings it works without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VSCode to test your example, and for what I could notice your tsconfig.json has an extra ,

Right after "noLib": false,

I've removed it, restart VSCode and it's working using:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
console.log(moment().startOf('day'));
```

Comment: Yep that was a type in my post, but even then I get the same error.
It compiles fine, but at runtime int fails with:
 `TypeError: moment is not a function`

Comment: OK, the problem now it's at runtime. Are you bundling your files? If not, have you included the moment.js file in your page?

Comment: Yes, if I "import" it with `const moment = require('moment');` everything works. For any other library we use it works, only with type definition files of moment we ran into this issue.

Comment: Check the section CommonJS libraries from this article, maybe it will help you understand. http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/